# How to insert external libraries INTO websites with Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium

I'm using Selenium Webdriver with Javascript to create automated software guides (https://github.com/aside-ufba/guide-automator).

I want to use the Popper library (https://popper.js.org) into the websites that i'm documenting.

Have a way to do it with executeScript function of Selenium? Like export libraries to an website and use it. Like a 'import'.

Comment: Just insert it into your selenium framework.  Then call it with executeScript when you need it.  You may need to do some coding on your side to get it to work, but it's possible.

Comment: Can i just import the library?